# AppleScript running Atom text-editor every time script is run instead of when if statement is true

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm new to AppleScript and I'm trying to make a simple AppleScript that will pop-up a dialog asking for user input and based on the input it will open one application or another. To do this I've used:

```
tell application "atom" 
activate
end tell
```

One of the applications is stored on an external hard drive called Tardis. The problem with my code below is that it automatically opens Atom every time I run the script AND the dialog window at the same time. I only want it to open Atom when the input a is given. Thanks for the help! Code is below:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set inputText to text returned of (display dialog "Options: p - a - j" default answer "")
    set p to "p"
    set a to "a"
    set j to "j"
    if (inputText = p) then
        tell application "Terminal"
            if it is running then
                do script "cd Python_Workspace; source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate"
            end if
            activate
        end tell
        tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/Volumes/Tardis/EXTRA Applications/Sublime Text.app"
    end if
    if (inputText = a) then
        tell application "Atom"
            activate
        end tell
        tell application "Terminal"
            if it is running then
               do script ""
            end if
            activate
        end tell
    end if
    if (inputText = j) then
        tell application "Terminal"
            if it is running then
                do script "cd /Java_Workspace"
            end if
            activate
        end tell
        tell application "IntelliJ IDEA CE"
            activate
        end tell
    end if
    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

So some applications that support Applescript do - or did, require the application to launch to compile the Applescript at all (if I remember correctly these are applications that support Applescript poorly, which I'm betting is Atom).

This may not be exactly what's happening, especially since if you are launching a compiled Applescript, but maybe you are running a .applescript (text) file.

What I would do, instead of `tell application "Atom" to activate` (a one line version of what you have), instead: `activate application "Atom"`.

If that does work for you, `activate` vs `tell` here's what's going on:

1. Applescript notices you're talking about Atom. It needs a dictionary to translate your typing into... events.
2. Applecript can't find the dictionary, so it launches the application, hoping that it can get more information from it when it launches
3. Atom launches, Applescript realizes that every application supports `activate`.

Where `activate application` you're not trying to do anything Atom specific... just activate an app. No dictionary lookup required.

(It's also worth noting that I've been doing this a very long time. I could actually be quoting you information that's a decade or more out of date, or "new" in 10.4 - not 10.14, but 10.4)